# Creating a matrix from panda df to display prediction between Disease_Symptom

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix

hello all i'm begginer in python datafram ::

i have my dataframe in pandas like the following format
header[Disease, Symptom]

```
    Disease     Symptom
   0 di1         sy1
   1 di1         sy4
   2 di1         sy7
   3 di3         sy2
   4 di3         sy4
   5 di3         sy7
```

##di = disease, sy =symptom

i want to study the prediction to each disease associated to symptom, i would like if some one can help me to create the matrix script
provide information if each disease associate to symptom..

```
ID  s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7
di1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
di2  0  1  0  0  0  1  1
di3  0  1  0  1  0  0  0
di4  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
di5  0  1  0  1  0  0  0
```

the idea is if one disease across to symptom in matrix print 1 if not associated to that symptom print 0

if anyone help me much appreciate! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by a combination of [pandas.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby).

For simplicity, I am creating my initial data-frame as follows:

```
>>> df
  Disease Symptom
0      d1      s1
1      d1      s4
2      d1      s7
3      d3      s2
4      d3      s4
5      d3      s7
```

I can use `pd.get_dummies()` method to generate dummy columns for the Symptoms feature.

```
>>> df_g = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['Symptom'])
>>> df_g
  Disease  Symptom_s1  Symptom_s2  Symptom_s4  Symptom_s7
0      d1           1           0           0           0
1      d1           0           0           1           0
2      d1           0           0           0           1
3      d3           0           1           0           0
4      d3           0           0           1           0
5      d3           0           0           0           1
```

Now, I can pack multiple rows using `df.groupby()` as per the column value of `Disease` and sum those one-hot encoded vectors to get the final desired result.

```
>>> df_gg = df_g.groupby(['Disease'], as_index=False).sum()
>>> df_gg
  Disease  Symptom_s1  Symptom_s2  Symptom_s4  Symptom_s7
0      d1           1           0           1           1
1      d3           0           1           1           1
```

The `Symptom_s3` and `Symptom_s5` are simple zero columns and can be appended later. My example `df` doesn't have `s6` to get the column through `get_dummies()`.

Comment: by the way its great script ....please how i can remove Symptom_ befor s name jut displas s1 or s4...ect name without Symptom_thanks

Comment: Hi, You can do it by passing the custom parameters to `prefix` and `prefix_sep`. Replace the code to generate `df_g` with the following `df_g = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['Symptom'], prefix=[''], prefix_sep='')`. This should give you the desired result. The documentation links provided in the answer should help with the explanations.

Comment: thank you very much its working%...#Sri Raghu Malireddi